# image kernel filter not producing correct results

Tags: java, imagefilter

I written some code that will change the dimensions of my image kernel filter. You can choose 3x3, 5x5 or a 7x7 matrix. The problem is when I switch to 5x5 or 7x7 only the cells in the first 3 rows and 3 columns works. So they act like a 3x3 matrix. An example of how I know its not working is when I try to apply the identity matrix using the 5x5 or 7x7, where I'll have zeros everywhere except the center cell, which will have a one. For me this produces a black image.

Here is the code that applie the image kernel

```
for (int y = 1; y < img.height-1; y++) {   // Skip top and bottom edges
    for (int x = 1; x < img.width-1; x++) {  // Skip left and right edges
          float sumR = 0; // Kernel sum for this pixel
          float sumG = 0; 
          float sumB = 0; 
      for (int ky = -1; ky <= 1; ky++) {
        for (int kx = -1; kx <= 1; kx++) {
          // Calculate the adjacent pixel for this kernel point
          int pos = (y + ky)*img.width + (x + kx);
          float rVal = red(img.pixels[pos]);
          float gVal = green(img.pixels[pos]);
          float bVal = blue(img.pixels[pos]);
          // Multiply adjacent pixels based on the kernel values
          sumR += kernel[ky+1][kx+1] * rVal;
          sumG += kernel[ky+1][kx+1] * gVal;
          sumB += kernel[ky+1][kx+1] * bVal; 
        }
      }
      //For this pixel in the new image, set the rgb value
      //based on the sum from the kernel
      edgeImg.pixels[y*img.width + x] = color(sumR,sumG,sumB);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use this code with 5x5 and 7x7 kernels.

If that's the case, the problem are this lines:

```
for (int ky = -1; ky <= 1; ky++) {
for (int kx = -1; kx <= 1; kx++) {
```

Because it's always going to loop exactly 3 times.

Supposing the kernel size is stored in a variable `kernel_size`, that could be the new code:

```
// Calculate the distance from the center to the edge
int side_width = (kernel_size-1)/2

for (int y = side_width; y < img.height-side_width; y++) {   // Skip top and bottom edges
    for (int x = side_width; x < img.width-side_width; x++) {  // Skip left and right edges
      float sumR = 0; // Kernel sum for this pixel
      float sumG = 0; 
      float sumB = 0; 

for (int ky = 0; ky <= kernel_size - 1; ky++) {
    for (int kx = 0; kx <= kernel_size - 1; kx++) {
        // Calculate the adjacent pixel for this kernel point
        int pos = (y - side_width + ky)*img.width + (x - side_width + kx);
        float rVal = red(img.pixels[pos]);
        float gVal = green(img.pixels[pos]);
        float bVal = blue(img.pixels[pos]);
        // Multiply adjacent pixels based on the kernel values
        sumR += kernel[ky][kx] * rVal;
        sumG += kernel[ky][kx] * gVal;
        sumB += kernel[ky][kx] * bVal; 
    }
}

  //For this pixel in the new image, set the rgb value
  //based on the sum from the kernel
  edgeImg.pixels[y*img.width + x] = color(sumR,sumG,sumB);
}
```

}

I have not tested this code but the idea should be clear.